# How to add border to image on hover?

Tags: css, border

I am trying to add a border to an image on rollover.  The border is not showing when I roll over the image.  Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imgBorder").hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass("Hover"); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass("Hover"); }
    );
});
</script>
Hover { border: 1px solid #000; }
<div id="imgBorder"><a href="#">link...</a>
```

Why isn't the border appearing on hover?

Also, is there any way to do this so that it does not re-size the image when adding the border?

Comment: is there any way to do this so that it does not re-size the image when adding the border?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use javascript to add hover on image rollover. Just add it to the css class instead.

```
<style language="text/css">
.rollOver : hover
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<div class="rollOver" id="imgBorder">Test</div>
```

Comment: Note that IE6 does not support the :hover selector on anything but anchors.

Answer (score 1):

First, to affect the image, your jQuery should be:

```
$("#imgBorder img").hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass("Hover"); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass("Hover"); }
);
```

And your CSS should be:

```
.Hover { /* note the period preceding the 'Hover' class-name */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NykWx/).

Note that:

- `.string` selects element(s) by their class-name of `string`: `<div class="string"></div>`
- `#string` selects an element by its `id`, which is equal to `string` `<div id="string"></div>`
- `string` selects an element of `string`: `<string></string>`

But you don't need JavaScript, just use:

```
#imgBorder:hover img,
#imgBorder img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NykWx/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work in CSS, link below

```
.rollover_img {
width: 280px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(land.jpg); 
background-position: top;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border:10px solid #ccc;
font:13px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:18px;
float:left;
margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

I will direct you to the following link

http://aceinfowayindia.com/blog/2010/02/how-to-create-simple-css-image-rollover-effect/

Answer (score 0):

In your selector below, you're targeting an element with the tagname "Hover". This does not exist.

```
Hover { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

What you wanted instead was:

```
.Hover { border: 1px solid #000 }
```

As others here have already pointed out, you don't need JavaScript for this as you can use the `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
img { border: 1px solid #FFF }
img:hover { border-color: #000; }
```

For further reading, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes